# There can be degeneracy in 1D energy eigenfunctions even if one of them and its derivative does to zero as $x\to\infty$?

Tags: wavefunction, mathematical-physics, schroedinger-equation, differential-equations

In 1D, the energy eigenvalue equation for an energy value $E$
$$
-\frac{\hbar^2}{2m}\psi''(x) + V(x)\psi(x) = E\psi(x)
$$
can have at most two linearly independent solutions, $\psi_1$ and $\psi_2$, with their Wronskian, $\psi_1'\psi_2 - \psi_1\psi_2'$ being a constant. Then it is said that

> if $\psi_1$ is such that it and its first derivative go to zero as $x\to -\infty$ or $x\to\infty$, then this Wronskian is uniformly zero.

It is then used to show that $\psi_1$ and $\psi_2$ are linearly dependent.

However, consider the functions $f(x):=x^2$ and $g(x) := 1/x$. Clearly they are linearly independent, with their Wronskian being the *nonzero* constant $3$, while $g$ anf $g'$ both go to zero as $x\to\infty$. Of course these functions are not appropriate candidates for the eigenfunctions, but what's the guarantee that even the eigenfunctions obeying the imposed BC's can't show such behavious?

So clearly, there have to be additional hypotheses in the quoted statement to conclude the constant Wronskian being zero. **What are they?**

Comment: Would this be better over on Mathematics SE?

Comment: [Here, p.48](https://nms.kcl.ac.uk/eugene.lim/teach/QM2012/allchapters.pdf) is a proof for the ground state. Also, I found but did not check out this reference: "One can also prove that the ground state (lowest energy solution), if one exists, is unique and
has even parity. In fact, one can prove the stronger result that the ground state wavefunction is
unique, real and strictly positive, which implies that it must have even parity. See for example,
volume 4 of Reed and Simon, “Methods of Modern Mathematical Physics”, Theorem XIII.4.6."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A possible additional condition is that $\psi_2$ and $\psi_2'$ are bounded. Then

$$\lim_{x\to\infty}\psi_1' \psi_2=\lim_{x\to\infty}\psi_1 \psi_2'=0$$

and since the Wronskian is a constant, this constant must be identically $0$. But if $\psi_2$ or $\psi_2'$ are unbounded, then it might be that $\lim_{x\to\infty} \psi_1'\psi_2\ne0$ and similarly for the second term, and then the result doesn't necessarily hold, as your counterexample shows.

I think this is just a sufficient condition, and one could perhaps come up with an example where $\psi_2$ and $\psi_2'$ are both unbounded and the two limits happen to match, or the difference happens to converge to $0$, but since in QM boundedness is usually a requirement, this should be enough to clarify your doubt.

Comment: You require more than bounded, for quantum mechanics one needs square integrable

Comment: @ohneVal But boundedness is sufficient here, isn’t it?

Comment: @ohneVal Also, as far as I can see, boundedness of $\psi’$ (which is apparently necessary for the argument in the above answer) *doesn’t* follow from $\psi$ being square integrable.

Comment: Agree, what I am saying is from the physical point of view, a non- square integrable function would make liitle sense in QM.

Comment: It's worth noting that in order for $\psi$ to be in the domain of the Hamiltonian in the first place, then $\psi''$ must be in $L^2(\mathbb R)$.  This implies that both $\psi$ and $\psi'$ are bounded.